# MODX getPage caches non cacheable snippets in 1st resource, how to fix the bug

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates, modx-chunks, modx-resources

I have a strange problem. I use getPage to view some similar resources. They have one template and same resource options. The problem is that getPage trying to cache my non-cacheable snippets in the 1st element. If u see next code, u can notice the difference.

```
 'output' => '<div class="thumbnail">20:21:54 </div> ... <div class="thumbnail">[[!showDate:gt=`0`:show]]</div> ... <div class="thumbnail">[[!showDate:gt=`0`:show]]</div>'
```

Heres link on "full" version http://pastie.org/7372941

As u can see, only first elements renders even if i didnt want it, pls help me to fix, i was trying ... but theres too much code 4 me in the core.

Comment: а `&cache=false` пробовал?

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с той же самой проблемой... Пришлось извращаться :(

Создал dummy ресурс, который прописал в критериях выборки через `` &resources=`dummy-id` `` и установил его свойства таким образом, чтобы он выводился всегда первым. В моем случае поставил дату `publishedon` на 20 лет вперед. Потом для `getResources` прописал `` &tplFirst=`@INLINE <div></div>` ``, чтобы   этот ресурс не отображался. Ну и напоследок выставил для `getPage` количество отображаемых ресурсов на первой странице на 1 больше через параметр `` &pageOneLimit=`[[+page_size:incr]]` ``

---

*A not very good translation by Google*

Faced with the same problem ... Had subverted: (

I created a dummy resource that prescribed in the criteria for selection through `` & resources = `dummy-id` `` and set its properties so that it is always displayed first. In my case, set the date `publishedon` the next 20 years. Then for `getResources` prescribed `` & tplFirst = `@ INLINE <div> </ div>` ``, that this resource is not displayed. And finally set to `getPage` the number of displayed resources on the front page for one more in a parameter `` & pageOneLimit = `[[+ page_size: incr]]` ``

Comment: Stack Overflow requires that you post in English. A translation by Google would do.

Comment: Я так и знал ))) Была такая же мысль, но я не решился так делать ибо боялся, что где то может вылезти баг связанный с особенностями двигла. Спасибо большое !!! Правда уже решил вопрос написанием собственного сниппета и класса для работы с выборками по ТВ.